# Python behaves differently for left shift of 1 and power of 2

Tags: python, integer, out-of-memory

I tried to compute `1 << sys.maxsize` on my system, python straight away gave me a 
Memory error but when I tried to do `2 ** maxsize`  python started computing it without any memory error.
**Despite the fact that 1 << a is equivalent to 2 ** a. (for all positive a)**
 Why this behaviour ?

**case 1:**

```
import sys
1 << sys.maxsize
```

**case 2:**

```
import sys
2 ** sys.maxsize
```

Result for **case 1:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-0d82f9d0b2eb> in <module>()
----> 1 1 << sys.maxsize

MemoryError:
```

Result for **case 2:**

```
# This kept on going without any memory error
```

Comment: Because power takes longer to calculate than a shift?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I waited about 1.5 minutes still no memory error. In case of shifting it was like in an instant. Are you sure this is the only reason ?

Comment: You just didn't wait long enough for the `MemoryError` to occur.

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure.

Comment: @jasonharper Now I waited 30 minutes...still no memory error. I think 30 minutes are more than enough for an overflow to occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 operations are equivalent in the way that they yield the same result.

> ```py
> >>> import sys, math
> >>> sys.maxsize, (sys.maxsize + 1) // 8, math.log((sys.maxsize + 1) // 8, 1024)
> (9223372036854775807, 1152921504606846976, 6.0)
> ```

As seen above, none of the 2 operations makes any sense, since (on *64bit*) the result would take ***1 EiB* (*exbibyte*) which is 1048576 (> a million) *TiB* (*tebibyte*s) !!!**, so they both would run out of memory at some point.

According to [[Python 3.docs]: Built-in Types - Numeric Types — int, float, complex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex):

> Integers have unlimited precision.

In the (*C*) source code, *Python*'s *int* value is represented as an `unsigned short []` (*longintrepr.h*), and the 2 functions are *long_lshift* and *long_pow* ([[GitHub]: python/cpython - (master) cpython/Objects/longobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c)).

This is (the simplified version of) how the 2 functions work:

- *lshift*: tries to allocate the required bytes to hold the **final** result - which fails (almost instantly)
- *pow*: performs successive multiplications, increasing the space needed by the **intermediate** result (you can issue `2 ** sys.maxsize` and look how the used memory grows in *Task Manager*, and if <kbd>Ctrl + Break</kbd> in *Python* console, the memory will drop). 
  Multiplication is an expensive (*CPU* and time wise) operation (even if there are speedups for it), there are also memory allocation / copy operations involved, so given enough time, the intermediate result will grow until it won't fit into the largest available memory block, and therefore it will fail (with the same error)

I'm not sure why for the number ***2*** (as base), the 2<sup>nd</sup> function doesn't simply call the 1<sup>st</sup> one, but I guess an additional *if* clause wouldn't justify as (it would introduce a small overhead for all the other numbers and) no one would / should use such an insanely large exponent.